# Meaning of a waste of time in a specific sentence.

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading [this article](http://thesefootballtimes.co/2016/01/14/the-disputed-genius-of-arsene-wenger/), there is a sentence as follow:

> It would be foolish, not to mention a waste of time, to recount Wenger’s glories at Arsenal

I don't understand what does it mean by *not to mention a waste of time* here.

Does it mean it's a waste of time if not recount Wenger's glories at Arsenal?

Please explain for me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The part after not to mention can be substituted for the part just before it.

> It would be foolish to recount Wenger's glories at Arsenal.

But I could also mention that

> it would be a waste of time to recount Wenger's glories at Arsenal.

The writer means that there are so many glories, and everybody knows about them, that it would be a waste of time to mention all of them.